# Cerrar y volver abrir la aplicación en Android (Restart App)

Tags: java, android

Tengo en la sección Configuración un selector para escoger el idioma de la app, independientemente de que se establezca por el sistema, pero me encuentro que para que surja efecto en toda la app, es necesario cerrar la app y volverla abrir.

El código para salir de la app uso lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

y en `MainActivity.java` dentro del evento `onCreate`

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
    finish();
    return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
}
```

Extraído de: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15939069/3464919)

**Update**
En la activity 'SettingsActivity.java' detecto el cambio del selector de idioma de la app y lo guardo en un `SharedPreference`

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("language")) {

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String value = sp.getString(key, "default");
        UsefulFunctions.SetLocaleLang(getBaseContext(),value);

        Toast.makeText(this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.pref_need_restart_app),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Para cargar el idioma independiente que se aplique el por defecto uso lo siguiente en cada Activity

```
String value = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("language", "default");

    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Pero me encuentro que solo se aplica el idioma si recargo de nuevo la activity o bien si se inicia de nuevo la app.

Solo me faltaría como volver a abrir la aplicación automáticamente.
En principio pienso que con una alarma que se lance XXX mili-segundos del cierre lance la aplicación eso es posible?

**Update2**
Gráficamente la carga de actividades  y lo que quiero realizar e poroblemas que me encuentro.

**Normal**

> SplashActivity(finish)->MainActivity(si touch backBtn se sale de la
>   app del todo)->Settings->FragmentGeneral(para cambiar
>   idioma)=>reiniciar_app

**reiniciar app:** problema con el back

> Splaschreen(finish)->MainActivity(cuando se hace backBtn, me devuelve
>   al FramentGeneral, y lo natural seria que se salga de ella)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para reiniciar por completo la app, lo soluciono estableciendo una alarma al sistema para que lance la Aplicación de nuevo.

En el `MainActivity.java`

```
if ( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)) {

    Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);

    finish();
    return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs

}
```

En mis pruebas mi *AcerZ200* como en la *Asus TF101* la app se reinicia sin percibir el tiempo, pero en mi *Motorola G*, cuando se cierra la app, va a la pantalla HOME de Android y después de 5 segundos o a veces más, no se abre de nuevo.
(Deduzco que no es la mejor forma de solucionarlo, pero funciona)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se realiza regularmente es simplemente realizar un intent para abrir la actividad de inicio de tu aplicación:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
intent.putExtra("ValorExtra", true); 
startActivity(intent);
finish()
```

e inmediatamente realizar un `finish()` para cerrar la aplicación, es opcional si necesitas recibir un valor en el bundle para realizar alguna acción.

Como comentario adicional en Blackberry OS 10 si portas tu aplicación Android, en lugar de `finish()` debes cerrar con `System.exit()`

Otras opciones para cerrar la aplicación si tienes cargadas varias actividades en el stack es simplemente llamar:

```
 super.finish();
```

I

Comment: Lo probaré a ver si se establece bien el  idioma establecido por el suario, solo con inicializar de nuevo desde la SplasScreen

Comment: Sería bueno saber un poco más como cambias el idioma, esto puede funcionar, pero otra opción por ejemplo es, si usas un adapter puedes realizar el cambio a las propiedades de los objetos que carga el adapter y únicamente ejecutar adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Se sitúa en el inicio de la app, pero si tiro para atrás me devuelve a la actividad donde se lanza el intent.
He probado de añadir intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
y tambien  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Ya tengo más o menos la solución

Comment: Entonces tu aplicación guarda varias actividades en el stack y de una que esta en un nivel superior de ahí deseas reiniciar. Recuerda también que puedes usar super.finish(). Si usas el flag Activity_no_history no se si desees no se guarde una actividad anterior en tu app.

Comment: he modificado la pregunta para que quede más claro lo que quiero realizar

Comment: Ok acabo de ver que lo que tienes son fragmentos los cuales estan guardados en la pila y cuando das "back" te devuelve a un fragmento anterior. :)

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar ..

```
finishAffinity();
startActivity(new Intent(act, actMain.class));
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte, no conocia lo de finishAffinity() probare si realmente en el Moto G, cierra y de seguida se vuelve abrir la app

Comment: espero te ayude ;)